# WebStorm Autocomplete with external JavaScript Library

Tags: javascript, node.js, autocomplete, protractor, webstorm

I am searching around the net about this for days and I can't find anything that solves my problem.
I want to include a library that I installed with npm in my JavaScript project so that I can get the autocomplete, see what methods/variables etc I have available.
Specificly I am trying to do this for Protractor.
Every single tutorial that I have found so far says the following:
`Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries -> Download -> TypeScript community stubs` but this is downloading TypeScript libraries, yes it adds autocomplete but it also adds stuff that is for TypeScript (interfaces and so on). I want to include the libraries that I have installed through the NPM how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Preferences -> Language&Frameworks -> Javascript -> Libraries` and click "Add". Here you can add directories or actual js files containing libraries you want to be added:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have tried that but it didn't work. Could you tell me exactly what I should add? Should I add the whole Protractor folder from the node_modules or I should add something really specific? If I install the TS Protractor library everything is really nice, the methods that I can use are bold and its really hard to get confused..

Comment: @Darkbound well, personally, I didn't have the need to add libraries via "Add..". I've just used "Download..." and downloaded everything presented on the screenshot. And now I have WebStorm helping me with autocompletes while working on protractor, jasmine or webdriver-specific code. In particular `angular`, `protractor`, `selenium-webdriver-DefinitelyTyped` are must have here.

Comment: When I click Download I have only the TS version of protractor.... I have two options to download from: Official Libraries or TypeScript Community Stubs. For Protractor there is only angular-protractor-DefinitelyTyped